# I need guidance on building a staking smart contract for my ERC 721 NFTs

Tags: erc-721, staking

I have written a smart contract in solidity using remix that will mint ERC721 NFTs. I now want to write another smart contract that will stake the NFTs. My code for the minting contract is below, any help or guidance for the staking contract would be greatly appreciated.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";

contract MooNFT15 is ERC721("MooNFT15", "MOO15"), Ownable {
    
    uint256 public tokenCounter;
    uint256 public price = 10000000000000000; // 0.01 AVAX
    uint256 public MAX_TOKENS = 100; // maximum supply
    string public baseURI = "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmNgD8iXt3HWxPazLvv5xNz8d1GYreTuMyp58AAc3PBenB/";
    
    using Strings for uint256;

    
    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal virtual override(ERC721) {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
    
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override(ERC721) returns (bool) {
        return interfaceId == type(IERC721Enumerable).interfaceId || super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
    
    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override(ERC721) returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
    }

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256) {
        return tokenCounter;
    }

    
    function mint() public payable {

        

        require(tokenCounter < MAX_TOKENS, "ERC721: Max supply");
        

        if (tokenCounter > 2) {
            price = 20000000000000000; // 0.02 AVAX

        } else {
            price = 10000000000000000; // 0.01 AVAX
        }
        
        require(msg.value == price, "The price of the NFT is 0.01 AVAX");
        _safeMint(_msgSender(), tokenCounter);
        tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
        

    }
    
    function withdraw() onlyOwner external {
        payable(owner()).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far for staking?

Comment: FYI, an open discussion on these topics, you are welcome to attend my weekly NFT/Web3 Community Service Hour. https://phor.net/#speaking

Comment: @WilliamEntriken I have tried creating a new contract called MooStake, but I keep getting this error when trying to transfer the NFT from the owners address to the newly implemented contract (MooStake). The error is "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved". I am getting this error even though I have called the approve() function before initiating the transferFrom() function.